# How to avoid XRUN callback skips

Tags: jack, ardour

After I set QjackCtrl and Arour, I can record fine, but XRUN callback skips are annoying.

This is my QjackCtrl configuration:

> [image]

In logs I see:

```
18:37:22.041 XRUN callback (97).
18:37:22.793 XRUN callback (42 skipped).
18:37:24.794 XRUN callback (111 skipped).
18:37:26.795 XRUN callback (111 skipped).
18:37:28.796 XRUN callback (111 skipped).
18:37:30.798 XRUN callback (75 skipped).
18:38:45.359 XRUN callback (552).
Mon Oct 20 18:38:45 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Running
Mon Oct 20 18:38:45 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:38:45 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
18:38:46.833 XRUN callback (3 skipped).
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Sink was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:38:46 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
18:38:48.834 XRUN callback (23 skipped).
18:40:28.031 XRUN callback (580).
Mon Oct 20 18:40:28 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Sink was not finished, state = Running
Mon Oct 20 18:40:28 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
18:40:28.884 XRUN callback (1 skipped).
Mon Oct 20 18:40:28 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:40:28 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Sink was not finished, state = Running
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Sink was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Sink was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client PulseAudio JACK Source finished after current callback
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Running
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Sink was not finished, state = Running
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = PulseAudio JACK Source was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackEngine::XRun: client = ardour was not finished, state = Triggered
Mon Oct 20 18:40:29 2014: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessGraphAsyncMaster: Process error
18:40:30.885 XRUN callback (32 skipped).
18:40:32.887 XRUN callback (89 skipped).
```

What are XRUN callback skips? How can I solve these problems?

Running Ubuntu 14.04 using low-latency kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 3.13.0-38-lowlatency #65-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 9 12:04:28 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: An xrun is a buffer overrun or underrun; you probably need to increase the frames/periods value.  On my particular rig, I have to set up the sample rate, frames/period, and periods/buffer such that the total latency is at least 16 msec.  Don't know if that's the *right* thing to do, but it minimizes the xruns by quite a bit.

Comment: @JohnBode Did you ever figure out if it was the correct way?

Comment: @KarlMorrison I just added an answer. Probably it's a hardware limitation.  Really recommend an audio interface (I'm really happy with Scarlett 2i2).

Comment: @IonicăBizău I'm running a Scarlett 2i4 myself heh, probably not got it setup correctly

Comment: @KarlMorrison Hmm, I just installed Ardour 4, QJackCtl, set up the QJackCtl options and started Ardour. Everything works as expected, no `XRun`s...

Comment: @IonicăBizău May I aks what settings you have on qjackctrl? Are you using your computers coud card as oupt or are you going back via the scarlett with it's outputs (to the moniters)?

Comment: @KarlMorrison Ah, no, I'm using the realtime feature provided by audio interface. That allows us to not feel any delay in the headphones. That's probably the key.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Indeed I have realtime enabled. What ms delay do you have currently? (I don't know what to set for Periods/Buffer, Frames/Period and Sample Rate)

Comment: @KarlMorrison Don't know real numbers, but I remember I set it to give me the best quality (~50msec, not sure if milliseconds or seconds).

Comment: @IonicăBizău Oh... I was able to get mine down to 5.33msec heh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30030/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-karl-morrison).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bumped into this again and finally have the correct answer to why xruns happen.

From JACKS page:

> Specify the number of frames between JACK process() calls. [b]This
>   value must be a power of 2[/b], and the   default is 1024. If you need
>   low latency, set -p as low as you can go without seeing xruns. A
>   larger period size yields higher latency, but makes xruns less likely.
>   The JACK capture latency in   seconds is --period divided by --rate

You need to set your `sample rate`, `frames/period` and `periods/buffer` correct. Below is optimal for **usb devices**.

```
(Frames [or buffer] / Sample Rate ) * Periods = Latency in ms

( 16 / 48000 ) * 3 = 1
( 32 / 48000 ) * 3 = 2
( 64 / 48000 ) * 3 = 4
( 128 / 48000 ) * 3 = 8
( 256 / 48000 ) * 3 = 16
( 512 / 48000 ) * 3 = 32
( 1024 / 48000 ) * 3 = 64
( 2048 / 48000 ) * 3 = 128
( 32 / 96000 ) * 3 = 1
( 64 / 96000 ) * 3 = 2
( 128 / 96000 ) * 3 = 4
( 256 / 96000 ) * 3 = 8
( 512 / 96000 ) * 3 = 16
( 1024 / 96000 ) * 3 = 32
( 2048 / 96000 ) * 3 = 64
( 64 / 192000 ) * 3 = 1
( 128 / 192000 ) * 3 = 2
( 256 / 192000 ) * 3 = 4
( 512 / 192000 ) * 3 = 8
( 1024 / 192000 ) * 3 = 16
( 2048 / 192000 ) * 3 = 32
```

I took the most optimal, all of them are here:
http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/list_of_jack_frame_period_settings_ideal_for_usb_interface

Comment: That's cool stuff. Tho, in my case it was a hardware limitation I guess. By buying an audio interface, I solved the issue.